# Dynamic bit vector in C/C++

Tags: c++, bitmap

I am looking for an off-the-shelf dynamic bit vector in C or C++ that I can use. Unfortunately for various reasons I cannot use the BoosT libraries at the moment. std:bitvector looks promising but it is templated so I cannot set the length of the bit vector dynamically. Can anyone advise? Thanks!

Comment: can't you use `vector<int>` as a base for your bitvector?

Comment: and you can use reserve as many data as you want or just call push_back

Comment: What is it about Boost that disqualifies it? I ask because I want to make sure the *other* third-party classes people might recommend don't also suffer from the same things that prevent you from using Boost.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/551579. Also, please list your requirements in detail. Do you need to access the bits in packed form with a C pointer? If so, you can implement your own resizable bit container using `vector<char>` or `vector<int>` together with some bitwise operations.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/q/670308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to put a dependency onto all of boost and its installation process just to use `dynamic_bitset`.  If the class suits your purposes, copy the source files for it specifically into your project tree and put it in a separate namespace called "boostcopy" (or something like that).

On a similar note, I made my own resizable array class modeled after dynamic_bitset called "Nstate", which you can template to an arbitrary radix and still get tight packing.  Perhaps of interest:

http://hostilefork.com/nstate/

Answer (score 2):

I have never used vector<bool> (See Scott Meyers' Effective STL item 18)  but it might be just what you are looking for.